# can support vector regression be used in large data?

Tags: regression, svm, large-data

My aim is to predict a continous variable with a support vector regression. However, my dataset is large. My question is if it is possible to use SVR in this case.

Comment: What makes you doubt SVR in such a situation?

Comment: Because I need to use SVR with non linear kernels such as polynomial kernels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not going to be ok since the kernel that needs to be present is quadratic in terms of number of samples. Of course, implementation details of the library do also matter. `sklearn` doc [suggests](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) kernel approximation in such large datasets.

Comment: Would it be slower than training a neural network?

Comment: It can be, for example because of the memory consumption (might not even fit-in) and swap-space etc. The computational complexity present in the convex opt problem has also quadratic terms regarding kernel multipliers. You can always early stop a neural net, but in SVM you won't have a choice other than sit and wait.

Answer (score 0):

SVR with polynomial kernel would probably fail as it is computation and space costly. Check out the datascience stack exchange link [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/996/110888) to understand more.

Empirical backing: I tried experimenting with 7008 samples of training data, and I initialized three regression models in scikit-learn:

1. SVR with a linearly separable hyperplane
2. SVR with rbf kernel parameters of C(penalty term) = 100, gamma=0.1, epsilon= 0.1
3. SVR with polynomial kernel with parameters C (penalty term) =100 and 1, gamma = auto, and epsilon = 0.1

The first and the second model were able to predict 1752 instances, but for the model with polynomial, my Google Colab Notebook crashed.